# Counting up within a text string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to create an excel spreadsheet that can automatically count up within a text string when I pull the cell down to drag copy it. Something that would look like below.

> APR2016-**0001**-OS
>   APR2016-**0002**-OS
>   APR2016-**0003**-OS

and so on. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the program to automatically count up just the numbers. After several hundred rows, it gets tedious, and the formatting of monthyear-#-OS is a necessity.

Comment: Do those numbers represent days and you need the APR to roll over to MAY at the end of the month?

Comment: If, as Forward Ed suggests, the numbers are dates, and if you can live with `Apr` instead of `APR`, you could merely custom format as `mmmyyyy-\0\0dd"-OS"`, enter `4/1/16` in the first cell, and fill down.  If not, then look at Jeeped's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let it do the count down method, and then when you are done, sort the column in Ascending/descending order to suit your needs.

Alternatively lets say you know what you want as the max number, you could use something like this:

```
="APR2016-"&RIGHT("000"&($B$1+1-ROW(A1)),4)&"-OS"
```

Copy that down, and place your starting number (largest) in B1.

I may have, nope I did, misread your question when you said count up.  I thought you wanted the numbers to go in the opposite direction as you were dragging.  If you want the numbers to increase as you drag then the formula simplifies to:

```
="APR2016-"&RIGHT("0000"&(ROW(A1)),4)&"-OS"
```

Column A has first formula, column B has second formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As introduced by [Forward Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094120/counting-up-within-a-text-string-in-excel/37094132#37094132), incrementing as you drag/copy/fill down/right is a simple matter of a relative [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) or [COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) function supplying the number to format in a [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) function.

Constructing the date portion with *year, month, day* integers could also increment the displayed MMMYYYY portion with a little maths.

In B1 and A2 as standard formulas,

```
=UPPER(TEXT(DATE(2016, 4, 1), "mmmyyyy"))&TEXT(COLUMN(A:A), "-0000-O\S")
=UPPER(TEXT(DATE(2016, 4, 1), "mmmyyyy"))&TEXT(ROW(1:1), "-0000-O\S")
```

Fill right or down as appropriate.

[image: increment_row_col]

Comment: I like that formatting the text function.  I dont think I have ever used, but I definitely like it.  Just have to remember it exists the next time I try to do something like that.